# Fragments and commas

Tags: grammar, commas

In

> I enjoyed the intellectual challenge of my previous engineering roles, but competition is what truly motivates me. I also relish the process of perfecting a difficult skill. Be it, out-manoeuvring an astute opponent at the poker table or executing a text-book cover drive in a cricket match.

and

> I scored exceptionally well on experimental modules that required significant academic writing. Writings that explain complex ideas, similar to how an attorney would explain problems with the prior art that an invention is aiming to solve.

Is the last sentence of each paragraph a fragment? By its own it makes no sense. But taking into consideration the previous sentence, it does. Am I taking the definition of a fragment too literally?

Are the commas in the last sentences of each paragraph right? In the first paragraph, "Be it" is introductory so a comma follows, right? In the second one, I feel there should be one before "similar", but then we have a independent clause followed by a comma followed by a dependent clause, which is wrong??

Comment: You are not taking a fragment too literally. But how often do you want that stylistic jolt? And a little goes a long way in using spices. Is a job cover letter the  place to show off your wordsmithing individuality? Yes and no. Do it if applying for poetry, not engineering.

Comment: Another idea: Remove the word 'I' from the head of most sentences.  My scores, rather that "I scored."  "Perfecting a difficult skill excites me" replaces "I relish."

Comment: 'Be it' should not be followed by a comma.  (It could be followed by a colon if introducing a list.)  Also, 'be it' could be preceded by a comma and simply used in apposition to 'a difficult skill'.

Comment: Why do so few people answer the questions (I mean "officially" - no offense intended whatsoever)? They are always answered in comments. This question is even upvoted and edited by a very senior member. So it obviously has some merit? I just absolutely do not get why comments are so preferable. Smh.

Comment: @Kace36 - That really should be asked in meta, not under a question. But one short answer to your query is that answers are supposed to be researched and substantiated. Sometimes someone might want to chip in with a helpful nudge but not take the time to research the matter and compose a full-fledged answer. (In this case, e.g., I think both of those are indeed fragments and should be offset from the main sentence with a comma or dash – but I don't have time to go checking my hunch in punctuation guides.)

Comment: @J.R.J Thx J. Appreciate the response. What is meta exactly? I'm sure I can find it but does it have a more general forum use (as you seem to indicate)? Thx again!

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I've modified my paragraphs to get rid of fragments and reduce the use if "I". Does this sound good now?                                                                          
"I have too much passion and ambition to be an engineer. I enjoyed the intellectual challenge of my previous engineering roles, but competition is what truly motivates. Additionally, the endeavour to perfect a difficult skill spurs me on, be it out-manoeuvring an astute opponent at the poker table or executing a text-book cover drive in a cricket match."

Comment: And, "The challenging curriculum of my physics degree equipped me with a strong academic base to understand some of the more complex patents out there. My grades in experimental modules were exceptionally high. Those modules required me to explain complex ideas similar to how an attorney would explain problems with the prior art that an invention is aiming to solve. "     I gave entire paragraphs just to give context. Thanks agian